# Dynamic memory allocation of an array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

Working in c. I am trying to dynamically allocate an array that is within a struct. The array will hold rows of char data. I can't see any errors, any help is appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data
{
    char **d;
}Data;

int main(void) 
{
    Data *a = malloc(10*sizeof(Data));
    int i = 0, length = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char buffer[1000] = { '\0' };
        printf("\nenter data\n");
        fgets(buffer, 1000, stdin);

        length = strlen(buffer);
        a[i].d[i] = malloc(sizeof(length+1));  //errors here, unhandled exception
        strcpy(a[i].d[i], buffer);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", a[i].d[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: before you access `Data.d` at index `i`, d must be allocd to have defined behaviour. so first you alloc the `char **` and then alloc your `char *`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `char **d` is a pointer to a pointer. And malloc returns `void*` type !

Hence,

1. type mismatch is there.
2. You have to first allocate the array of pointers. That is  `a[i].d=malloc(row*sizeof(char *);`

   Then you can do `a[i].d[i] = malloc((length+1)*sizoef(char));`

Comment: Actually in C `void*` is assignment compatible with any pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[i].d[i]
```

The double use of `i` here is a red flag. This should be either `a[i].d` or `a.d[i]`. It looks like you're intending to store 10 strings, one per `Data` object. In that case, your struct declaration should contain `char *` not `char **`.

```
typedef struct data {
    char *d;
} Data;
```

And then the lines assigning to `d` would become:

```
a[i].d = malloc(length + 1);
strcpy(a[i].d, buffer);
```

That gets rid of the double `[i]` indices. Each `Data` object contains one string named `d`. In the loop, you allocate memory for that string and then copy `buffer` into `d`. All good!

Notice also that I've gotten rid of the `sizeof` inside the malloc() call. You want to allocate `length + 1` characters. No need for `sizeof`. If you want to be more explicit you could change `length + 1` into `(length + 1) * sizeof(char)`—but you don't have to, because `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, the

```
malloc(sizeof(length+1));
```

makes no sense.  You mean

```
malloc(length+1);
```

`malloc` allocates in units of `char`s.  The `sizeof()` operator returns the size in `char`s of the type or object that is it's argument.  `length+1` is not a suitable argument.

Next, you seem to mean to be reading an array of strings.  The struct is not contributing much to the problem solution.  Consider throwing out the structs and using just an array of pointers to characters (i.e. an array of strings of varying lengths), or else keep the structs and change the field to a `char*` type.

Additionally, if you don't know the number of strings in the file in advance, then you must grow the array dynamically with something like `realloc()`.

Here is the array of strings approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1000

int main(void) 
{
  int i, n, n_max = 8;
  char **a = malloc(n_max * sizeof(char*));

  for(n = 0; ; ++n)
  {
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE + 1];  // zeroing buffer is a waste with fgets

    printf("\nenter data or Ctrl-Z to stop\n");
    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) return;

    if (n >= n_max) {
      n_max *= 2;
      a = realloc(a, n_max * sizeof(char*));
    }
    a[n] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy(a[n], buffer);
  }
  // n now contains number of strings actually read

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%s", a[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```